# C++ EasyBMP Pointer Issue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

The following code is causing a Segmentation Fault on the .ReadFromFile line:

```
int main()
{
// Load in.bmp
BMP * original;

cout << "line " << __LINE__ << ": Got here!" << endl;
original->ReadFromFile("in.bmp"); //Error HERE!
int width  = original->TellWidth();
int height = original->TellHeight();
cout << "line " << __LINE__ << ": Got here!" << endl;
```

I'm using the EasyBMP library, which is included above the main function. I know it has something to do with memory and pointers, but I can't figure out what to use in place of "original->"... I've tried (*original). and (&original). but I can't seem to get it. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointer `original` is pointing to a random memory location. Trying to use it will cause the undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory for `BMP` object and store the address in this pointer. If you want your object to persist even after it goes out of the function use `original = new BMP();`(don't forget to `delete` it later though) else you can directly do `BMP original;` and use it.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared BMP as a pointer but never initialized it.

Try using:

```
BMP original;
```

or

```
BMP *original = new BMP();
```

The first method will create original on the stack, and you won't have to release it. The second method creates it in the free-store, and you need to use delete to free it.

```
delete original;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the tutorial, your code should be:

```
BMP Image;
Image.ReadFromFile( argv[3] );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a pointer try this:

```
// Load in.bmp
BMP original;

cout << "line " << __LINE__ << ": Got here!" << endl;
original.ReadFromFile("in.bmp"); //Error HERE!
int width  = original.TellWidth();
int height = original.TellHeight();
cout << "line " << __LINE__ << ": Got here!" << endl;
```

or if you need to use the heap do:

```
BMP* original = new BMP();
```

and when you are done don't forget to free the memory

> delete original;